# Get foreign key table property MVC

Tags: model-view-controller, model, sql-server-2012, foreign-keys

I have a student model with a departmentID foreign key. And the Department model has two property, ID and code. I cannot access the department code by the departmentID from student table. And yes I have this,

```
        public virtual Department Department { get; set; }
```

in my student model. I tried this,

```
student.Department.code
```

but it returns null. I have no idea what I am missing. And I need the value to generate a student reg no. before saving student data. like this,

```
student.RegCode = student.ID + student.Department.Code;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first you had to call a variable to match the id and receive Department object

```
var code = db.Departments.Where(u => u.ID == student.DepartmentID).FirstOrDefault();
```

once you have your object data on a variable, you can access all its properties. like below,

```
student.RegCode = code.code+ "-" + student.ID;
```